# Display returned list in Code Behind in my dropdown list in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list which is generated in my code behind but I need to then pass this list to my dropdown list in my view, but I have no idea on how to do this as I am new to development.

**Code behind**

```
List<AJBG.ServiceContracts.Messages.ThirdPartyAPIs.Origo.GetStaticCedingSchemes.CedingScheme> origoCedingSchemes = target.GetStaticCedingSchemes(request).cedingSchemes;
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (AJBG.ServiceContracts.Messages.ThirdPartyAPIs.Origo.GetStaticCedingSchemes.CedingScheme origoCedingScheme in origoCedingSchemes)
{
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = origoCedingScheme.schemeName, Value = origoCedingScheme.counterPartySchemeOrigoId.ToString(), Selected = false });
}
var selectItemList = listItems as List<SelectListItem>;

return selectItemList;
```

**View**

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Scheme_TextBox", "", new { style = "width:98%;", PlaceHolder= "Type to search...", onblur="SelectedScheme(this);" })%>
```

I have tried using `viewData` but my list is still not displayed

Comment: you have to use ``Html.DropDownList``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Sorry my mistake, I changed it to `DropDownList` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML List control with "runat=server" and add data in code behind in control.